# What are 'standard' parameters to try when hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning

I'm curious what parameters people tend to tune for various models and the values they try. For instance, on [this post](https://ryan-reilly.medium.com/gridsearch-pipelines-of-multiple-models-on-multiclass-classification-e9124b6ea2e3), the author had a go-to set of parameters he would use for tuning.
What is the basis on which I should choose parameters/values? Should the set of parameters/values change depending on the problem/project I'm working on?

Relatedly what are your go-to parameters/values for models (e.g., the ones in the post i.e., LogisticRegression, DecisionTree, RandomForest, KNeighbors, SVM, XGB)?